# When has hydrogen peroxide been used in rocketry?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, fuel, hydrogen-peroxide, smallsat-launcher

Peroxide is apparently a very good propellant, but I can't seem to find any instance of it being used. Has it ever been used and if not, why hasn't it? What's its downsides?

Comment: Related: [HTP as oxidizer for main propulsion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41219/htp-as-oxidizer-for-main-propulsion)

Comment: It was used starting with the first "real" rocket https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-2_rocket but just to run the turbopump

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hydrogen peroxide has a (perhaps not fully deserved) reputation of being hazardous to work with; it decomposes spontaneously, releasing heat, and the decomposition rate increases with temperature, so it's tricky to store safely. An [old usenet discussion thread](https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/fuels/peroxide.html) found on Yarchive discusses the hazards in more detail.

It is used sometimes as a monopropellant (using a catalyst bed for ignition) for small reaction-control thrusters, notably in the [X-15 spaceplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15) and in the Soyuz spacecraft's descent module's control thrusters.

As Organic Marble notes, it's also been used to drive turbopumps in early pumped bipropellant rockets such as the [German V-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-2_rocket) and [US Redstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGM-11_Redstone), and is still used for this on the Soyuz booster.

It's also been used as an oxidizer for larger bipropellant rockets, such as the UK's kerosene-peroxide [Black Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Arrow).

Kerosene/peroxide has also been proposed [as a propellant combination for reusable SSTO launchers](https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/fuels/hydrogen_deltav.html); while it doesn't have as good *mass*-specific impulse as hydrogen/LOX, peroxide is relatively dense, making for a smaller launcher with correspondingly less mass spent on thermal protection, and the lower mass-specific impulse actually has an advantage in delta-v needed to reach orbit.

Comment: The Me 163 Komet rocket fighter plane used stabilized H2O2 ("T-stoff") as oxidizer in its bipropellant engine. Appallingly hazardous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_163_Komet

Comment: and it's the peroxide that limits how long Soyuz is allowed to stay at the ISS as a reliable return craft with attitude control: [Does the Soyuz spacecraft use chemically stabilized hydrogen peroxide (H₂O₂) to remain ISS-dockable for 200+ days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31337/12102)

Answer (score 6):

Hybrid smallsat launch vehicle technology is currently being developed 100% in Taiwan<sup>1</sup> by the [Advanced Rocket Research Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Rocket_Research_Center) along with all control electronics and algorithms. The video below shows a test with four hybrid peroxide oxidizer plus <s>rubber</s> thermoplastic solid engines being both vectored and throttled to implement stable hovering. I think that the plan is to include a much larger hybrid engine in the middle for higher altitude (> 100 km) tests in 2021 with the eventual goal of reaching orbit (potentially N2O + thermoplastic) with these providing attitude control.

<sup>1</sup> I've been a fan for years but no affiliation.

From the first video below (**note:** this is a non-technical translation of a snippet of an interview):

> **Reporter:** The team’s goal is to create a satellite launch vehicle. They’ll direct it into orbit at least 100 kilometers above the Earth’s surface, to carry out scientific experiments.
>
> **Wu Tsung-hsin** (Advanced Rocket Research Center) I went to the U.S. with this thing and their eyes lit up. You can make a liquid-propellant rocket, no problem, **but this is really the first hybrid-propellant rocket in the world.**
>
> **Reporter:** National Chiao Tung University professor Wu Tsung-hsin is known by students as Uncle Rocket. With a team of 15 professional researchers and over 30 undergrads and graduate students, he hopes to make the first 100% Taiwanese rocket. That would let the nation launch its own satellites into space, without assistance from institutions overseas.

Example of a 1200 N H2O2 + thermoplastic closed-loop throttling and re-ignition engine test

Example of a 10 kN Isp 224 s (sea level) N2O + thermoplastic engine test

Comment: Burt Rutan is sad to hear that his hybrid motor that took humans to space does not count. " this is really the first hybrid-propellant rocket in the world."

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'll add a note that the translation by the non-technical reporter may not be accurate. Translations between Chinese and English are fraught with errors. That said, it could also be an accurate translation. It's a snippet, perhaps the difference between *air-launch from a very expensive airplane* and a *far simpler and cheaper ground launch* was part of a much longer interview that this was excerpted from.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Russell Borogove's mention of Black Arrow, I can add that the engines of Black Arrow were [Bristol Siddeley Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Siddeley_Gamma), where 85% hydrogen peroxide was used not only as an oxidizer (with approximately 8:1 mixture oxidizer/fuel ratio), but also as a nozzle coolant.

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article, already catalytically decomposed (and very hot) peroxide was used in combustion chamber (so oxygen was a really oxidizer, although cold peroxide is chemically an oxidizer itself).

Answer (score 3):

[Armadillo Aerospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo_Aerospace) attempted to use both [90% hydrogen peroxide](https://www.globalsecurity.org/space/systems/armadillo.htm) and later switched to hydrogen peroxide (50% concentration in water) and methanol as a mixed monopropellant for their vehicle.

My internet-fan memories were that, at least with the 90% solution, they were having severe problems getting a consistent burn and tried many catalyst and injector configurations until they stopped being able to get 90%. Their blog and website appears to have disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another addition to Russell Borogove's answer:  hydrogen peroxide was used for the Mercury capsule's [attitude control](http://www.space1.com/Artifacts/Mercury_Artifacts/Mercury_Thrusters/mercury_thrusters.html), and the [AMU experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaut_propulsion_unit#USAF_Astronaut_Maneuvering_Unit) attempted on Gemini 9.

Answer (score 1):

According to ["Development of Hydrogen Peroxide Monopropellant Rockets"](https://www.esa.int/gsp/ACT/doc/PRO/ACT-RPR-PRO-JPC2006-HP%20Rockets%202006-5239.pdf) (.pdf, 2006) by Angelo Cervone, Lucio Torre, Luca d’Agostino, Antony J. Musker, Graham T. Roberts, Cristina Bramanti, and Giorgio Saccoccia:

> Alta  S.p.A.  (Italy)  and  DELTACAT  Ltd.  (United  Kingdom)  are  conducting  a  study, funded   by   the   European   Space   Agency,   into   the   **development   of   hydrogen   peroxide monopropellant  thrusters**  using  advanced  catalytic  beds.  The  present  paper  focuses  on  the design  of  two  different  demonstration  thrusters  with  nominal  ratings  of  5  N  and  25  N. Design  requirements  and  specifications  are  presented,  followed  by  the  main  results  of  a concept  study,  which  was  conducted  to  define  the  approximate  dimensions  needed.    Some details about the specific design of the two prototypes and the choice of the main components are  provided,  with  particular  regard  to  the  sensors  and  transducers  to  be  used  during  the experimentation.  Different  catalytic  bed  configurations,  including  pure  silver  gauzes  and pellets  coated  with  manganese  oxide  or  platinum,  are  going  to  be  tested  in  the  prototype thrusters, in order to find the optimum one for further industrial development. A dedicated test bench, designed and  realized by Alta  S.p.A. for  tests  on  the thruster prototypes, is  also illustrated.

And:

> The most promising high-energy green propellants, like ADN, HAN and HNF (Wucherer et al.1, Schoyer et al.2), are  based  on  complex  organic  molecules  and  compensate  the  large  molecular  weight  of  their  decomposition products with high operational temperatures of the exhaust gases. As a consequence, it is necessary to use extremely expensive materials and manufacturing processes for the thrust chamber and, at the same time, the operational life of the  catalytic  beds  is  drastically  reduced.
>
> **Hydrogen  peroxide**,  on  the  other  hand,  does  not  suffer  from these disadvantages  and  has  therefore  been  reconsidered  as  a  promising  green  propellant  for  low  and  medium  thrust applications.